# Oracle dual query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT X.Y( 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', '100') 
  FROM dual
```

I know what dual is but this part `X.Y( 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', '100')` really makes me wonder. What does this syntaxis mean?

Are `X` and `Y` tables or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I can see three possibilities:

1. X is a schema, and Y is a function within X's schema.
2. X is a package, either with a public synonym or in the current schema, and Y is a function defined in that package.
3. X is a type, either with a public synonym or in the current schema, and Y is a function defined in the type.

What does the SQL*Plus command `DESCRIBE X` or `DESCRIBE X.Y` return?

Comment: Thank you. 'Desc' really worked and it was a function in procedure.